# adding an Action to MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, ios7, mapkit

(Using Xcode 6)

My Tracking button is on the right side of the Nav Bar, it wont trigger the method and i have no idea why, this is supposed to be the right way.

The button itself is functional.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //location initial settings:
    firstLaunch = YES;
    self.mapView.delegate = self;

    [self.mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];

    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

    [locationManager setDelegate:self];

    [locationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];
    [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
    currentCentre = self.mapView.centerCoordinate;
    //create a thread queue
    [self queryGooglePlaces: currentCentre];

    //navBar:

    MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem *trackButton = [[MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem alloc] initWithMapView:_mapView];
    [trackButton setTarget:self];
    [trackButton setAction:@selector(track:)];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = trackButton;
}

-(void) track: (id) sender {
    NSLog(@"clicked !");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that you can use `MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem` in this way -- it already has a target (the associated map view) and an action (changing the tracking mode). Instead I would look into `-[MKMapViewDelegate mapView:didChangeUserTrackingMode:animated:]` to respond to map mode changes when the button is clicked.